# CurrentUser is null on Sharepoint 2010 application page

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010, spcontext

I have application page, hosted on Sharepoint server (for ex. http://myportal/mysite/_layouts/application/default.aspx), which has code like this:

```
protected void Page_PreLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
{           
    var userEmail = SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.Email;
}
```

If user tries to get this page directly by URL after browser starts, exception appears, because CurrentUser is null.
But if user firstly navigates to web site (http://myportal/mysite) and then to application page, CurrentUser is not null.
So, how can I get CurrentUser object if it is not initialized in SPContext?

Answer (score 0):

Getting the current user from an elevated SPWeb inside a RunWithElevatedPrivileges code.
Try this code.

```
SPWeb site = SPContext.Current.Web;
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
{
    using (SPSite ElevatedsiteColl = new SPSite(site.Url))
   {
       using (SPWeb ElevatedSite = ElevatedsiteColl.OpenWeb())
       {
            SPUser currUser = site.CurrentUser; //not the ElevatedSite.CurrentUser
       }
   }
});
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly site.CurrentUser is null.

Answer (score 0):

Well... better late than never.  I ran into this same problem today.  The previous comment does not address the original poster's expressed problem.  The problems comes when you publish .ASPX pages in the _Layouts folder, and then, when using Forms or Claims auth, make that custom page your first hit in a session (with no previously remembered login).  SharePoint authentication isn't fired by default (even if you inherit from the LayoutsPageBase class).  If you navigate to some other SharePoint page (such as _Layouts/15/Settings.aspx) and then come back, then the CurrentUser *is* filled in.  I had to use Reflector to get a better clue of what was going on, and how to fix it.  The short answer is, once you realize that the CurrentUser == null, you need to add this line of code:

```
Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility.HandleAccessDenied(new UnauthorizedAccessException());
```

In my case, this code generates a challenge/response to the browser, which I used to log in, and immediately following this line of code, the CurrentUser object is filled in correctly.  Here is what my entire function ended up looking like:

```
public static bool isAdminAuthorized()
{
    Microsoft.SharePoint.SPContext oContext ;
    Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb oWeb ;
    Microsoft.SharePoint.SPUser oUser ;
    try
    {
        oContext = Microsoft.SharePoint.SPContext.Current;
    }
    catch { throw new Exception("Can't obtain Sharepoint Context!"); }
    try
    {
        oWeb = oContext.Web;
    }
    catch { throw new Exception("Can't obtain Sharepoint web!"); }
    try
    {
        oUser = oWeb.CurrentUser;
    }
    catch { throw new Exception("Can't obtain Sharepoint current user!"); }
    if (oUser == null)
    {
        Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility.HandleAccessDenied(new UnauthorizedAccessException());
        oUser = oWeb.CurrentUser;
    }
    foreach (Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGroup oGroup in oUser.Groups)
    {
        if (oGroup.Name.ToUpper().Contains("OWNER"))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```